# Flutter clickable ListWheelView is jumping to wrong index

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, indexing

I am using [ClickableListWheelView](https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view). There is a problem when scrolling and `clicking` an item below the `selectedItem`, it jumps to the wrong `index`.

I already opened an issue, here you can see more details: [https://github.com/Cilestal/clickable_list_wheel_view/issues/1](http://Github-Issue)

I thought about how to fix it:
Since this only happens when scrolling, more specifically when scrolling down and selecting an item from below the selected item:

Maybe you could add a listener variable "`isScrolling`" and also a
"`isScrollingUp`"/"`isScrollingDown`" and `if (isScrollingDown) { index = currentIndex - indexOffset } else { index = currentindex + offset }`

This is the `code` from `ClickableListWheelView`:

```
  double _getClickedOffset() {
    if (_tapUpDetails == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    return _tapUpDetails.dy - (_listHeight / 2.0);
  }

  int _getClickedIndex() {
    final currentIndex = widget.scrollController.offset ~/ widget.itemHeight;
    final clickOffset = _getClickedOffset();
    final indexOffset = (clickOffset / widget.itemHeight).round();
    final newIndex = currentIndex + indexOffset;

    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= widget.itemCount) {
      return -1;
    }

    return newIndex;
  }
```

Any idea on how I can fix this? I can not make it work...